# Find $U(x,y)$ given boundary conditions

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I have this equation: with a and b not equal to 0.

[image]

If we solve the partial differential equation:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Now I am given the boundary conditions $U(x,0) = x^2$ .How do I continue?

Comment: I am not really sure you are allowed to put images instead of latex in the question. Looks nice though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You found a characteristic equation $\quad x-\frac{a}{b}y=c$.

The general solution of the PDE is :
$$U(x,y)=F\left(x-\frac{a}{b}y\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function until no boundary condition be taken into account.

CONDITION :

$$U(x,0)=x^2=F\left(x-\frac{a}{b}0\right)$$
$$F(x)=x^2$$
Now the function $F$ is determined. We put it into the above general solution where the argument is $\left(x-\frac{a}{b}y\right)$ :
$$U(x,y)=\left(x-\frac{a}{b}y\right)^2$$